# Should I enable TRIM support in Mac OSX 10.6.7 for SSD with SandForce SF-2281 controller (Vertex 3)?

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro

Recent articles in [Mac Rumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1125400) and [Life Hacker](http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd) (which actually reference [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/265694/how-to-prevent-programs-e-g-process-monitor-from-killing-my-ssd-in-2-weeks) on SU) say that using TRIM will prolong the life and increase the performance of an SSD.

I just got an [OCZ Vertex 3](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-vertex-3-sata-iii-2-5-ssd.html) with the SandForce SF-2281 controller.  Does this drive need TRIM support to operate at max performance? What about longevity?  Isn't the built in Sandforce garbage collection enough?

[image]

#### Edit for clarity:

I'm aware of the the various methods of enabling TRIM support on my MacBook Pro.  The question is whether or not the new [Sandforce Controllers](http://www.sandforce.com/index.php?id=3) need TRIM?

Answer (score 4):

Apple only supports TRIM on [their own SSDs](http://www.betanews.com/article/Get-what-Apple-wont-give-TRIM-support-for-3rdparty-SSDs/1301330225), but there are [ways around this](http://www.hardmac.com/news/2011/03/27/the-universal-solution-to-activate-trim).

The [AnandTech review](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4256/the-ocz-vertex-3-review-120gb/13) of the OCZ 120GB Vertex 3 shows that, in the worst possible case of writing lots of incompressible data to the drive, there can be a substantial drop in performance without TRIM.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will get more out of the SSD enabling TRIM. Several people have experienced performance issues without it on OS X.

You **don't need any firmware update** to do this, but still OS X Snow Leopard doesn't have it built in yet (10.7 will however).

You can download [TRIM Enabler](http://www.groths.org/?p=308) which does exactly that. I've been running a Macbook Pro with an SSD for several months now using it, no problems at all.

Comment: @slhck What drive do use?  Enabling TRIM caused lots of problems and short freezes.

Comment: @Chris_O I know, I recall seeing your other question. Glad you got it fixed. I have one designated as "Apple SSD T5128C", although I don't remember having heard of practical differences between Apple and non-Apple drives - a friend of mine uses some OCZ without issues.

Comment: Do you know which OCZ model?

Comment: @Daniel No, haven't seen him in a while. Why?

Comment: I'm in the market for an SSD (Vertex 3 possibly) and am a bit skeptical regarding TRIM on OS X. Known good experiences would be useful.

Comment: @Daniel It's a Vertex 2, so that won't really help I guess... But they should make it work, at least with 10.7? OCZ aren't *that* uncommon.

Comment: Yeah, with a release within two months I can probably go that long without TRIM on 10.6. Thank you!