# Beachballs and short freezes after enabling TRIM and restoring from Time Machine (Mac OS X)

Tags: freeze, crash, macbook-pro

I decided to enable TRIM for my SSD based on the recommendations from [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/285725/should-i-enable-trim-support-in-mac-osx-10-6-7-for-ssd-with-sandforce-sf-2281-con).

Something went wrong and I couldn't boot and ending up having to restore from Time Machine.

#### Edit:

I manually replaced the binary file

IOAHCIFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOAHCIBlockStorage.kext/Contents/MacOS/IOAHCIBlockStorage

with one that was edited and fixed the permissions.  ***I missed the part about your first boot might take a long time (the machines normal boot time is 8 sec)***  I only gave it a couple of minutes and tried to reboot a few times.

I tried to manually fix it by restoring the backup I made of the binary via Terminal but still wouldn't boot.

I also successfully enabled TRIM after restoring and reset PRAM, verified disk and repaired permissions.

The second time I just used the Trim Support Enabler

Now I'm getting beachballs and short freezes.  It usually happens in Chrome but also TextMate.  I had none of these problems before.

How can I determine if the problem stems from enabling TRIM or from the Time Machine restore?

Here is the error log from when it just happened a few minutes ago.

```
    <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x3c03c].com.apple.mail[409]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Mail[409] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x7a07a].com.datacolor.spyder3utility[708]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Spyder3Utility[708] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSShapeWindow
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro Google Chrome Helper[416]: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43: --- last message repeated 12 times ---
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x23023].com.google.Chrome[290]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[416] <Error>: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro Google Chrome Helper[416]: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x23023].com.google.Chrome[290]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[416] <Error>: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43: --- last message repeated 2 times ---
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro Google Chrome Helper[416]: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x23023].com.google.Chrome[290]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[416] <Error>: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro Google Chrome Helper[416]: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x23023].com.google.Chrome[290]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[416] <Error>: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro Google Chrome Helper[416]: unknown error code: invalid context
May 21 19:24:43: --- last message repeated 3 times ---
May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro [0x0-0x23023].com.google.Chrome[290]: Sat May 21 19:24:43 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro.local Google Chrome Helper[416] <Error>: unknown error code: invalid context
```

The Google Chrome 416 error is repeated about 30 times after what I posted.

Here is the beginning of the CrashReport

```
Process:         Console [658]
Path:            /Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/MacOS/Console
Identifier:      com.apple.Console
Version:         10.6.3 (224)
Build Info:      ConsoleX-2240000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [198]

Date/Time:       2011-05-21 17:29:49.043 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J4138)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000002000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:
```

This is the Kernal log from the freeze:

```
May 21 19:24:53 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19130. 19   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff8013bb0000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
May 21 19:24:53 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19130. 51   [0xffffff8017148c00] The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfd120000)
May 21 19:25:00 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19137. 20   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff8013bb0000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
May 21 19:25:06 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19143. 21   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff8013bb0000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
May 21 19:25:12 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19149. 22   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff8013bb0000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
May 21 19:25:18 Chris-Olbeksons-MacBook-Pro kernel[0]: USBF:    19155. 23   AppleUSBEHCI[0xffffff8013bb0000]::Found a transaction which hasn't moved in 5 seconds on bus 0xfd, timing out! (Addr: 0, EP: 0)
```

Comment: How old is the Time Machine backup? Did you make it before you replaced the HDD?

Comment: The time machine backup was the latest from an hour before I screwed up enabling TRIMM.

Comment: Hmm.. Could you clarify about what went wrong and why you had to reboot? Have you tried disabling TRIM and seeing if that works again? If not, restore the TM backup and don't enable TRIM, see if that works out. The restore would reset all your modifications from enabling TRIM.

Comment: The system misbehaves after you patch a kernel extension? I'm sure there's *absolutely no connection!* Have you actually read the warnings in the article linked from the other SU topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that was causing the problems was enabling TRIM.  I restored the kernal extension from my backup and all the problems immediately went away.

To make sure it wasn't a fluke I followed all the steps and re enabled TRIM and the problems came back.

Conclusion:  Don't hack the kernal to enable TRIM for a drive that doesn't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is verify the disk using Disk Utility and repair the disk if necessary.

Comment: Did all that including repairing permissions.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that.